# WSO2 ESB Asynchronous logging with better performance

Tags: logging, asynchronous, wso2-esb

We are using WSO2 ESB 4.8.0. ESB performance is decreasing When Debugging logging is enabled. 
We need a solution to capture request and response from ESB through log mediator and send to REST api asynchronously and the response should be sent to the client with out waiting while logging.

Please suggest any mediators or any sample tutorial how can we do logging asynchronously with out effecting any performance on ESB.

Answer (score 0):

Use clone mediator and manage logging in a dedicated target

In this target, just push your log message in a JMS queue or in JMS message store (OUT_ONLY)

Dequeue this logging queue in a dedicated mediation (use a message processor if you used message store, or define a JMS Proxy reading this queue)

It's asynchronous, in your mediations, logging will be fast and if your REST API is down or slow, you will not loose any message

Comment: We tried with the above solution and able to store only request payload and the response message, but not getting any request header details. In case of GET request we are getting the below error.org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Payload could not be written as JSON.
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:10
9)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStrea
mFormatter.java:60). Please suggest how can we store the request header details.

Answer (score 0):

The solution Jean-Michel is describing is called a WireTap.
If you need extra explanation or some implementation details and tricks w/WSO2 ESB check this link : http://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/implementing-wiretap-eip-in-wso2-esb-proxy-service/

Hope this helps